# Objective-C - How to trim chars from beginning and end of an NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I've looked all over for something as specific as the following:

I have strings imported where the source looks like this:

Z8 - Z8 FAIRLAND PARK        (147)

What I'd like to end up with is:

Z8 FAIRLAND PARK

I can create the first part ok:

```
NSArray* parts = [tempString componentsSeparatedByString:@"- "];
NSString* result = [parts count] > 1 ? [parts objectAtIndex: 1] : [parts objectAtIndex: 0];
//NSLog (@"result: %@", result);
```

I can accomplish the latter part with:

```
if ([result length] > 0) {
    result = [result substringToIndex:[result length] - 5];
}
```

But I know that's hokey.
What's a better way?

UPDATE:

Trying to respond to comments and ideas:

This is a bit larger sample of the data set: (note the Z9 route - it's truncated at the data source.

I suppose too that I could truncate all the route info in the Name field and use the RouteID for the name.

```
    {
    Name = "Z8 - Z8 FAIRLAND          (147)";
    RouteID = Z8c;
},
    {
    Name = "Z8 - Z8 FAIRLAND          (147)";
    RouteID = Z8v1;
},
    {
    Name = "Z8 - Z8 FAIRLAND          (147)";
    RouteID = Z8v2;
},
    {
    Name = "Z8 - Z8 FAIRLAND          (147)";
    RouteID = Z8v3;
},
    {
    Name = "Z8 - Z8 FAIRLAND          (147)";
    RouteID = Z8v4;
},
    {
    Name = "Z8 - Z8 FAIRLAND          (147)";
    RouteID = Z8v5;
},
    {
    Name = "Z8 - Z8 FAIRLAND          (147)";
    RouteID = Z8v9;
},
    {
    Name = "Z9 - Z9 LAUREL-BURTONSVILL EXP (104";
    RouteID = Z9;
},
    {
    Name = "Z9 - Z9 LAUREL-BURTONSVILL EXP (104";
    RouteID = Z9c;
},
    {
    Name = "Z9 - Z9 LAUREL-BURTONSVILL EXP (104";
```

Comment: You could use substringWithRange

Comment: You need to explain the pattern, the logic for which parts you want to remove. Also, give some more input and desired output strings.

Comment: Thanks. I'll dive into NSRange. Would I use two statements or one?

Comment: @KenThomases. I've provided a short example above, but I'll post a more detailed sample and explanation.

Comment: Yes, I see the example, but we can't generalize from a single data point.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good candidate for regular expressions, e.g. trimming off everything before the `-` as well as the number in parentheses at the end, like so:

```
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^.*? -\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\(\\d*\\)?" options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(regex, @"regex error %@", [error localizedDescription]);

NSString *string = @"Z8 - Z8 FAIRLAND PARK (147)";
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
if (match) {
    NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *result = [string substringWithRange:range];

    // use `result` here
}
```

This uses "capturing parentheses" to capture the string in the middle.

Clearly, I've made some assumptions about what you want to trim off the start and the end, but it illustrates the power of regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks Rob. That works nicely. I will still expand the question, as I want  to make sure it will handle all cases. It also gives me an opportunity to study RegEx a bit.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte Absolutely. By the way, if you update the question with more examples of the input or a more complete definition of the rules for determining what's trimmed off, I can probably refine this. I made a lot of assumptions on the basis of a sample set of 1, which is always dangerous. :)

Comment: Thanks all for the help. It's much appreciated. @Rob, Whats a good (simple) book for RegEx?

Comment: I don't know about particular books, but if you google "regex tutorial", you'll get a ton of great references. The only trick when using it in Objective-C is that the backslash character must be represented as two backslashes inside a `NSString` literal (because the backslash, itself, is an escape character for things like `\n` and `\r`). I admit that regex is a little opaque when you first encounter it, but is incredibly powerful text searching tool.